# services.addons.mozilla.org:443 uses an invalid security certificate

Tags: firefox

I just installed firefox 3.6.15 on windows 64. When I try to go to 'addons' I get this error:

```
services.addons.mozilla.org:443 uses an invalid security certificate.
```

Comment: First thing to check is your system date/time is accurate

Comment: this is all fine? what would be the fix?

Answer (score -2):

In Firefox, go to the "Tools" menu and select "Options". Under "Advanced" settings, choose the "Encryption" tab and click on the "View Certificates" button.

Now choose the "Servers" tab and click on the "Add Exception" button. Enter "services.addons.mozilla.org:443" in the "Location" field and then click on the "Get Certificate" button. Make sure that the "Permanently store the exception" box is checked, then click the "Confirm Security Exception" button.

This worked for me when I had the same error.

Comment: This is a dangerous suggestion, since the cause of the problem is unknown and the warning might be a sign of somebody intercepting the connction to the server. In such cases you should always check *why* the problem occus and then fix it the right way. If this specific problem still exists, visit https://services.addons.mozilla.org/ and look at the details in the error message to know why this happens.